# GpsStatus.Listener and GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX event

Tags: android, gps, android-2.2-froyo

When I register a GpsStatus.Listener I do not get the event `GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX`. I do get the `GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS` event.

Does anybody already noticed this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't get a fix, i.e. maybe you're sitting indoor or your location is surrounded by high buildings which blocks the satellite.